# spring neo4j: how can I search data by index field case insensitive?

Tags: java, indexing, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

Domain class as following:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Product{

   private Long nodeId;
   @Indexed(indexName = "productCode")
   private String code;
   ...
}
```

Repository class:

```
 public interface ProductRepository extends GraphRepository<Product>{       
       @Query(value="start product=node:productCode(code={0}) return product")
        public Set<Product> findProducts(String code);
    }
```

how can I make code lookup case insensitive?
I try regular expression and fail.Code as following:

```
 public interface ProductRepository extends GraphRepository<Product>{

       @Query(value="start product=node:productCode(code=~{0}) return product")
        public Set<Product> findProducts(String code);
    }
```

I know one way works but the performance will be not good, the code as following:

```
 public interface ProductRepository extends GraphRepository<Product>{
       @Query(value="start product=node:__types__(className='Product') where product.code='~{0}' return product")
                public Set<Product> findProducts(String code);
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried making the index full text and provide the entire lucene query as parameter? Set `type=indexType.FULLTEXT` in your @indexed annotation, replace `code={0}` with `{0}` and pass a query string per http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/queryparsersyntax.html into your `findProducts` method. Its been a while, but I think wildcard queries for instance are case insensitive, so passing something like "code:PrOdUcTcOdE*" should work.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to try and use where clause with regular expressions:

See the [latest 2.0 milestone](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-where.html#where-case-insensitive-regular-expressions) or [here for 1.9.5](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9.5/query-where.html#where-case-insensitive-regular-expressions)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The following query works but I think the performance should be lower as code is indexed. @Query(value="start product=node:__types__(className='Product') where product.code='~{0}' return product").