# Case insensitive filter in neo4j

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using Spring-data-neo4j to handle neo4j operations. I need to do a case insensitive search based on emailAddress property. I am using followinng code to do the filtering

```
session.loadAll(UserN.class, new Filter("emailAddress", "xyz@gmail.com"), 1);
```

Above code will not fetch records with emailAddress as XYZ@gmail.com because of upper case.  I don't want to write cypher query myself like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701091/spring-neo4j-how-can-i-search-data-by-index-field-case-insensitive) and looking for solutions which use Spring to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`LIKE`](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/8e269cb5264bd3f5e35e255d9151defd26400a83/core/src/main/java/org/neo4j/ogm/cypher/ComparisonOperator.java#L25) operator:

```
Filter filter = new Filter("emailAddress", "xyz@gmail.com");
filter.setComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.LIKE);
session.loadAll(UserN.class, filter, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked for me. I altered ur solution a bit like below
Filter filter = new Filter("emailAddress", "(?i)xyz@gmail.com");
filter.setComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.MATCHES);
I altered it because I wanted exact match instead of contains